# Random movement of sprite

Tags: swift, random, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

I'm new here so i apologize if i've entered my question wrongly. That said, i'm having an issue making my sprite move into random locations around the screen. here is my code

```
func random() ->CGFloat{
    return CGFloat(Float(arc4random()) / 0xFFFFFFFF)
}
func random(#min: CGFloat, max:CGFloat) ->CGFloat{
    return random()*(max-min)+min
}

dino.position = CGPoint(x: size.width + dino.size.width/2, y: actualY)
    // Add the monster to the scene
    addChild(dino)
    // Determine speed of the monster
    let actualDuration = random(min: CGFloat(3.0), max: CGFloat(4.0))
    let randomNum = CGPoint(x:Int (arc4random()%1000), y:Int (arc4random()%1000))
    // Create the actions
    var actionMove = SKAction:CGPoint(CGPoint(x:randomNum, y:randomNum)), duration:NSTimeInterval;(actualDuration)
    let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    dino.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))
```

thank you for helping, anything helps at this point

Comment: And what's wrong with your code?

Comment: What's the actual error you got or what's wrong?

Comment: `SKAction:CGPoint(CGPoint(x:randomNum, y:randomNum)), duration:NSTimeInterval;(actualDuration)` is not valid syntax in swift. The correct syntax would be: `SKAction.moveTo(randomNum, duration: NSTimeInterval(actualDuration))` Also why do you use `arc4random()%1000 `when you have `random(min: 0, max: 999)`

Comment: HOLY COW it worked! thanks a lot. Also to answer your question; i don't know, i was just  told it would help me in what i was trying to do. What does arc4random()%1000 mean if you don't mind taking the time to tell me?

Comment: arc4random() generates a random integer between 0 - 0x100000000. the modulo operator `%` get the remainder of a division so arc4random()%1000 will be between 0 - 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are using is not valid. Use `SKAction.moveTo` instead.

```
dino.position = CGPoint(x: size.width + dino.size.width/2, y: 10)
// Add the monster to the scene
addChild(dino)
// Determine speed of the monster
let actualDuration = NSTimeInterval(random(min: CGFloat(3.0), max: CGFloat(4.0)))
let randomNum = CGPoint(x:Int (arc4random() % 1000), y:Int (arc4random() % 1000))

var actionMove =  SKAction.moveTo(randomNum, duration: actualDuration) // Changed line

let actionMoveDone = SKAction.removeFromParent()
dino.runAction(SKAction.sequence([actionMove, actionMoveDone]))
```

Comment: it gives me an error saying CGFloat is not convertible to "NSTimeInterval"

Comment: did you notice the line `let actualDuration` where i convert the `CGFloat` to `NSTimerInterval`?

Comment: you can also do `var actionMove =  SKAction.moveTo(randomNum, duration: NSTimerInterval(actualDuration))` without changing the `actualDuration`